# Why can't I use the same parser twice in a tuple()?

Tags: rust, nom

I have written the following nom parser code:

```rust
use nom::character::complete::digit1;
use nom::combinator::map_res;
use nom::error::Error;
use nom::sequence::tuple;
use nom::Err;

type E<'a> = Err<Error<&'a str>>;

fn parse_double_int(input: &str) -> Option<(i32, i32)> {
    let num = map_res(digit1, |s: &str| s.parse::<i32>());
    let mut pair = tuple((num, num));
    let res: Result<_, E> = pair(&input.trim());

    match res {
        Ok((_, (a, b))) => Some((a, b)),
        Err(_) => None,
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `num`
  --> src\lib.rs:11:32
   |
10 |     let num = map_res(digit1, |s: &str| s.parse::<i32>());
   |         --- move occurs because `num` has type `impl FnMut<(&str,)>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
11 |     let mut pair = tuple((num, num));
   |                           ---  ^^^ value used here after move
   |                           |
   |                           value moved here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

How can I reuse the parsers I have defined locally?

Comment: Can you write a [MRE] ? There are too many missing parts here to answer you without guesses

Comment: @DenysSéguret I have added a "minimal" or at least self contained example failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map_res` return a `FnMut`. You can't move twice a `FnMut` cause `FnMut` doesn't implement `Copy`, than the obvious solution would be to borrow it, but you can't cause `Parser` require `mut` and you can't have multiple mutable borrow. So the last option is to implement a `Parser` that either implement `Copy` or can be create easily:

wrap the `FnMut` inside a `Fn` closure that Implement copy:

```rust
let num = |input| map_res(digit1, |s: &str| s.parse::<i32>())(input);
```

Create a function:

```rust
fn num(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, i32> {
  map_res(digit1, |s: &str| s.parse::<i32>())(input)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you have any pointer to explain this precise issue?

Comment: @insitu I may have rushed the explanation, you can't move cause FnMut doesn't implement copy, than the obvious solution would be to borrow the closure, but you can't cause Parser require FnMut and you can't have multiple mutable borrow. so the last option is to have implement a Parser that either implement copy or can be create easily, a function is the simpler on nom case.

Comment: Hmm, I see, this is odd but my Rust type system is still embryonic. So this means that declaring a top level function makes it copiable? Whereas a closure is not? Why would nom require a `FnMut` and not a plan `Fn` if such a thing exists?

Comment: @insitu this allow mutable state inside parser. Thus I'm not a big fan of this approach but it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

You are "moving the value" meaning that Rust is giving ownership of your value num and then freeing it (deleting it) when it is finished, you can try letting your function borrow the value with the &num notation, or cloning the variable if the struct implements the clone trait.
There is a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677430/how-to-fix-string-field-does-not-implement-copy) I can't recreate your problem with just the snippet but hopefully this gives you enough information to find the solution!

Comment: Thanks, but if I try to pass `num` as a reference, the compiler complains with ```11  |     let mut pair = tuple((&num, &num));
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an `Fn<(&str,)>` closure, found `impl FnMut<(&str,)>`
```

Comment: Ah I'm not familiar enough with nom to solve this for you, but it looks like you are getting a mutable function from `map_res` and tuple is expecting an immutable `Fn<(&str,)>` so you may need to find an alternative to map_res that returns the desired type. Good luck! sorry I couldn't be of more help.